# Is it grammatical to say "I had to make sure my dog stay asleep/ doesn't wake up until my mom came home"?

Tags: grammaticality, tense

I want to keep all the tenses consistent, so I am stuck between three choices.

1. I had to make sure my dog stayed asleep/did not wake up until my mom came home.
2. I had to make sure my dog stay asleep/does not wake up until my mom came back.
3. I had to make sure that my dog stay asleep/does not wake up until my mom come home.

Comment: It's probably "stays" asleep. With an 's'.

Comment: #1 is the only case that has a chance.

Comment: #1 is fine, depending on what you are trying to communicate. #2 and #3 are grammatically incorrect, mixing past (*had)* and present (stay -- or, rather, *stays* -- and *does*).

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct since all your verbs are in the past

> I **had** to make sure my dog **stayed** asleep until my mom **came** home.
>   I **had** to make sure my dog **did** not wake up until my mom **came** home.

You could put your third sentence all in the present with a simple change

> I **have** to make sure that my dog **stays** asleep until my mom **comes** home.
>   I **have** to make sure that my dog **does** not wake up until my mom **comes** home.

Comment: It's that present tense third person singular again, gets them every time :-)